# For circle reverse ..undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var text=(32243).toString().split("");
for(var i=(text.length -1);i===0;i--){
console.log(i);
}
```

I should get output as i equals 4,3,2..
but I'm getting `undefined` there has to be something that I'm missing

Comment: You loop will continue so long as the condition `i===0` is true. Since it's not true the first time through the loop, your loop doesn't run.

Comment: I get nothing, not even undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ...

```
for(var i=(text.length-1);i>=0;i--){
  console.log(i);
}
```

While `i>=0` ...

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how to set up the `for` loop. The for loop has three expressions

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [update])
```

The `initialization` expression sets up the loop. The `condition` is evaluated *before* each run of the loop and ***if it evaluates as truthy***, the loop body runs. The `update` is run at the *end* of each cycle of the loop and usually updates the loop variable.

In your example, you initialize `i` to `4` (the length of the string `"32243"` - 1). But your condition is `i===0`. `4===0` is, obviously, false, so your loop never runs.

Your `condition` should probably be `i>=0`.